# How do I get the outer product of two vectors in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to get the outer product of two vectors:

(1 2 3) x (1 2 3)

This should produce a 3x3 matrix, where each value is `ij`:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#In_programming_languages

How do I do this in KDB? (the Wikipedia page makes reference to J & APL, so there must be a clever way).

(I tried `x cross x`, which produces the right arguments, but doesn't actually calculate the outer product or produce right shape.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you want:

```
q)1 2 3*/:1 2 3
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

Multiply each right

This, and additional math-related KDB+ idioms can be found in documentation at https://code.kx.com/q/learn/q-by-examples/